# Winforms / Devexpress / Tab Control separation of concern / General code layout

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a single form application that consists of a split layout with a

- menu [left hand side]
- context menu [top]
- tab control [main section of the window]

Each menu item change option changes the current tab in the tab control and populate relevant data.

Can anyone suggest a way of `separating` the code out of the `single file` form.cs that I currently have? It's grown to `2,000 lines` and I have to use `regions` to keep it organised. If anyone has any examples that I could follow along with?

Any advice would be great.

Kind regards,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) keyword. You can create a file for each region and copy its contents to this file.
For example, the file **MyClass.cs**:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        //Code outside of region

        #region 0
        //Code for region 0
        #endregion

        #region 1
        //Code for region 1
        #endregion

        #region 2
        //Code for region 2
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Can be splited to several files:
**MyClass.cs**

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        //Code outside of region
    }
}
```

**MyClass_Region0.cs** (This file name is just for example. You can give it any name that you want.)

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        //Code for region 0
    }
}
```

**MyClass_Region1.cs**

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        //Code for region 1
    }
}
```

**MyClass_Region2.cs**

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        //Code for region 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further you can use UserControls to separate your code. Make one UserControl foreach TabPage for example can help you to keep you code smaller.